# Why is my debouncing/counter not working in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

i am currently trying to display a counter state on a 7-Segment.
If i push a button (physically) it should increase this counter state.
But in my case its displaying a random number, i think its a wrong debouncing/counter method.

I searched the web but i can´t fix this behaviour.
I would be very thankful if someone could help me!

EDIT: The 7-Segment-Display is working well i did a test with all numbers (0-9)
      So it is definetly failing in my debounce or counter method.

```
//debouncer.vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity Debounce is
   Port ( CLK100MHZ    : in  STD_LOGIC;
          BTNU  : in  STD_LOGIC;
          BTNU_I : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Debounce;

architecture Behavioral of Debounce is
signal keydeb : std_logic := '0';
signal debcnt : integer range 0 to 63 := 0;
begin
  process begin
     wait until rising_edge(CLK100MHZ);
     -- XOR
     if (BTNU=keydeb) then debcnt <= 0;
     else                   debcnt <= debcnt+1;
     end if;
     -- Latch
     if (debcnt=63) then keydeb <= BTNU; 
     end if;
  end process;
  BTNU_I <= keydeb;

end Behavioral;

//main.vhdl

//declared ports
Port ( 
          BTNU: in std_logic; //button
          CPU_RESETN: in std_logic;
          CLK100MHZ: in std_logic;
);
//declared signals
signal Qint10m: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); //number which holds the number to display   
signal BTNU_I: std_logic; //button debounced
signal testC: integer range 9 downto 0; //counter

BTNU_debounce:  entity Work.Debounce port map(
                      CLK100MHZ => CLK100MHZ,
                      BTNU => BTNU,
                      BTNU_I => BTNU_I);

bcd_counttest: process(CPU_RESETN, CLK100MHZ, BTNU_I)
begin
   if(CPU_RESETN='0') then
       testC <= 0;              
       elsif( CLK100MHZ'event and CLK100MHZ = '1') then
               if(BTNU_I = '1') then
                   if(testC = 8) then
                      testC <= 0;
                   else 
                    testC <= testC+1 ;
                   end if; 
            end if; 
    end if;
end process bcd_counttest;

Qint10m <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(testC, Qint10m'length));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't analyze (compile). It's not a [mcve]. Off hand 6 bits worth of debcnt (0 to 63) isn't enough to debounce a button with a 100MHz clock, the count should be in the ten millisecond range or longer depending on the button (switch). What's wrong with the btnu_i in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTtMf.jpg)?  (It's used as an enable for  the testc counter using the same clock. You want an enable a single clock long.) For simulation debcnt should be assigned 0 when 63.

Answer (score 0):

I did not check your code very well, but noticed a de-bounce counter of 63 on a 100MHz clock. That is 630 ns.

A button can easily bounces for several milliseconds (depending on the button type) . So I suggest you start with using a bigger counter.

<sub>p.s. I am not very familiar with VHDL but this:</sub>

```
wait until rising_edge(CLK100MHZ);
```

<sub>can not be synthesized in Verilog.

I suggest you have a good look at your whole debounce process as I also see no sensitivity list and a latch!</sub>

Comment: *I did not check your code very well, but...*  The signs that the question may not be a [mcve]. Does this answer ***Why is my debouncing/counter not working in VHDL?*** (which seems a bit broad).

Comment: A de-bounce settle time of 630 ns will not work. So that is definitely one source of error.

Comment: You could actually answer the question (which may require a [mcve]), See IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) 6.1.3.2 Edge-sensitive storage using a single wait statement, para 1, `wait until rising_edge(CLK100MHZ);` is synthesis eligible.